# Using Vue.js in a prestashop module

Tags: vue.js, prestashop

I would like to use Vue.js in a Prestashop module that I am creating, so I need to retrieve values from the database and affect some Vue.js variables with these values.

I think it would not be difficult doing this in Env mode (by making a query call to the database and affect the values to vue.js data) but in Production mode, I don't see how it can be done.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Why would production mode be any different?